# How to describe this set of maps of posets?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, permutations

Let $n\geq 1$. Let $[n]=\{0<1\}^n$ equipped with the product order. Let $f:[n]\to [n]$ be a strictly increasing map. When $f$ is bijective, there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $f(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n)=(\epsilon_{\sigma(1)},\dots,\epsilon_{\sigma(n)})$.

> Is there such a representation theorem when $f$ is not bijective ?

For $n=2$, the only maps are $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)\to (\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$, $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)\to (\epsilon_2,\epsilon_1)$, $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)\to (\min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2),\max(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2))$ and $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)\to (\max(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2),\min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2))$. For $n\geq 3$, things become more complicated and I am not aware of any canonical representation, or at least of a way of listing all strictly increasing maps $f:[n]\to [n]$.

**Motivation**: When $f$ is bijective or for $n=2$, I can see $f$ as a continuous map $[0,1]^n\to [0,1]^n$ which moreover, for people interested in directed homotopy theory, takes a directed path of $[0,1]^n$ to another directed path of $[0,1]^n$ preserving the initial and final states of the $n$-cube. I would like to do the same thing for the other cases.

Comment: Even classifying the images of such maps seems highly nontrivial. I don’t see why you couldn’t get e.g. every rank n graded poset this way.

Comment: @SamHopkins, some of them are easy to eliminate. In particular, if the second-lowest rank has all $n$ tuples with total weight 1 then the map must be bijective. To take another example, if $n=3$ and the ranks have restrictively 1,2,2,1 elements, one of the elements at rank value 1 has two successors at rank level 2, and the other has only one.

Comment: More generally, if two words $w_1, w_2$ of weight $k$ have Hamming distance 2, the Hamming distance of $f(w_1), f(w_2)$ must be at most 2, and if it is equal to 2 then $f(w_1 \vee w_2) = f(w_1) \vee f(w_2)$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't know what the Hamming distance is but all such $f$ have the property that $\epsilon_1+\dots+\epsilon_n=f(\epsilon_1)+\dots+f(\epsilon_n)$.

Comment: The Hamming distance is the number of positions in which the tuple/word differs. (The (Hamming) weight is the Hamming distance from $0^n$, and I think that your comment is intended to say that the Hamming weight of $f(w)$ is the Hamming weight of $w$, which follows easily from the property that the map is strictly increasing).

Comment: @PeterTaylor In the language of directed homotopy, the associated map from $[0,1]^n$ to itself not only will take a directed path to a directed path, but also the $L_1$-arc length from $0^n$ will be preserved (here it coincides with the distance for the $d_1$ metric): different words for the same phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way published in a recent preprint (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2209.02667).

> **Theorem**: Let $n\geq 1$. Let $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n):[n]\to [n]$ be a stricly increasing map. Then there is the equality  $
> f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \max_{(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n)\in
> f_i^{-1}(1)} \min \{x_k\mid \epsilon_k=1\}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

I explain the result with an example instead. Consider the map $f:[3]\to[3]$ depicted in the following picture (the top diagram is the source, the bottom diagram is the image):

[image]

Let $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. For boolean values, $\min$ means "and" and $\max$ means "or". If $x_1=1$ and $x_3=1$, or $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$ and $x_3=1$, then $f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1$. Thus $f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\max(\min(x_1,x_3),\min(x_1,x_2,x_3))$. If $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$, or $x_2=1$ and $x_3=1$, or $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$ and $x_3=1$, then $f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1$. Thus $f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\max(\min(x_1,x_2),\min(x_2,x_3),\min(x_1,x_2,x_3))$. Finally, if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$, or $x_1=1$ and $x_3=1$, or $x_2=1$ and $x_3=1$, or $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$ and $x_3=1$, then $f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1$. Thus $f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\max(\min(x_1,x_2),\min(x_1,x_3),\min(x_2,x_3),\min(x_1,x_2,x_3))$.

Comment: This theorem doesn't use that $f$ is *strictly* increasing. It treats each component $f_i$ independently of the others, and it amounts to saying simply that $f_i$ is a weakly increasing function to $\{0,1\}$. That is, the max and min in the formula for $f_i$ just say that $f_i(\vec x)=1$ iff $\vec x\geq\vec\varepsilon$ for some $\vec\varepsilon$ with $f_i(\vec\varepsilon)=1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You're perfectly right. I use _strictly_ increasing only to prove specific properties of the "topologification" of $f$.