# Removing the symmetry maps from a small category of cubes

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, permutations

Let $[1]^n=\{0<1\}^n$ equipped with the product order. I consider the small category $\widehat{\square}$ of the category of partially ordered sets generated by the *coface maps* $\delta^\epsilon_i:[1]^{n-1}\to [1]^n$ with $\epsilon=0,1$ defined by  $$\delta^\epsilon_i:(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) \mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},\epsilon,x_i,\dots,x_{n-1})$$ and by the strictly increasing maps $f:[1]^n\to [1]^n$.

The small category $\widehat{\square}$ contains the symmetry maps (the ones permuting the coordinates).

> Informally, I would like to remove the symmetry maps from
> $\widehat{\square}$, and only them, to obtain a subcategory of
> $\widehat{\square}$.

Every strictly increasing map $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n):[1]^n\to [1]^n$ gives rise to another strictly increasing map by permuting the coordinates. I need to find a way to make a choice among all permutations.

Every strictly increasing map $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n):[1]^n\to [1]^n$ satisfies the equalities  $$f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \max_{(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n)\in
f_i^{-1}(1)} \min \{x_k\mid \epsilon_k=1\}$$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/429941/24563).

> **Question:** In the formula above, is there a way to put a total order on the coordinates by using the syntax of the formula ?

**Motivation:** I work with the presheaves on $\widehat{\square}$ that I call *transverse sets*. They are a generalization of the category of precubical sets adapted for studying the directed homotopy for concurrency. And I would like to define the *non-symmetric transverse sets*. The two papers using transverse sets are [Combinatorics of labelling in higher dimensional automata](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.11.013) and [Directed degeneracy maps for precubical sets](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2209.02667).

**EDIT (I add some details to give some intuition):** a (too) naive idea consists of defining this subcategory of $\widehat{\square}$ by using this lemma:

> **Fact:** Every map $f:[1]^m\to [1]^n$ of $\widehat{\square}$ factors uniquely as a composite $[1]^m\to [1]^m \to [1]^n$ where the right-hand $[1]^m\to [1]^n$ is a composite of coface maps.

And then to consider the subset of maps of $\widehat{\square}$ factorizing like $[1]^m\to [1]^m \to [1]^n$ such that the left-hand map is not one-to-one unless it is the identity of $[1]^m$ and such that the right-hand map is a composite of coface maps. Unfortunately, this subset of maps of $\widehat{\square}$ is not closed under composition. Here is a simple counterexample.

- $f:[1]^2\to [1]^4$ defined by $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,0,0)$
- $g:[1]^4\to [1]^4$ defined by $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (x_2,x_1,\max(x_3,x_4),\min(x_3,x_4))$.

$f$ is a composite of coface maps. $g$ is not one-to-one since $$g(x,x,1,0)=g(x,x,0,1)=(x,x,1,0)$$ for $x=0$ or $x=1$. However $$(g\circ f)(x_1,x_2)=(x_2,x_1,0,0)$$ which means that $g\circ f$ is the composite of a nontrivial permutation map $[1]^2\to[1]^2$ followed by a composite of coface maps.

There are four maps in $\widehat{\square}([1]^2,[1]^2)$:

1. the identity $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)$
2. the permutation $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_2,x_1)$
3. $\gamma_1(x_1,x_2)=(\max(x_1,x_2),\min(x_1,x_2))$
4. $\gamma_2(x_1,x_2)=(\min(x_1,x_2),\max(x_1,x_2))$.

The idea would be to keep from $\widehat{\square}([1]^2,[1]^2)$ the identity and one of the two maps crushing the square transversally $\gamma_1$ or $\gamma_2$, and to find a way to do the same thing for all sets $\widehat{\square}([1]^m,[1]^n)$ in such a way that we obtain a subcategory of $\widehat{\square}$.

Comment: By "posets" you mean finite sets? And how do you get symmetries in that category? And isn't the only strictly increasing map $f : [n] \to [n]$ the identity?

Comment: @darijgrinberg $[n]=\{0<1\}^n$, not $\{1<\dots<n\}$. For example, the map $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto (x_2,x_1)$ is strictly increasing. Poset means partially ordered set.

Comment: This is a nice question, but may I suggest two notational changes might make it clearer?  Denoting the cube posets $[1]^n$ or $I^n$ rather than $[n]$ (both certainly occur in the cubical sets literature, but elsewhere $[n]$ is much more widely used for $\{0,…,n\}$, which the cubical sense clashes badly with); and using something like $\square'$ instead of $\widehat{\square}$, since $\widehat{-}$ is standard notation for presheaf categories, and in particular $\widehat{\square}$ is commonly used for the category of cubical *sets*, so it’s very confusing to see it meaning a small cube category?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Probably $[1]^n$ is better than $[n]$ indeed. I use a different notations for presheaves.

Comment: Ah, those are the $[n]$s here! Interesting, but yes, the notation should be better...

Comment: One thing you can do is work with the sorting maps. The $i$-th sorting map $r_i$ changes the entries $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ to $\min\left\{x_i,x_{i+1}\right\}$ and $\max\left\{x_i,x_{i+1}\right\}$, respectively. The sorting maps generate a copy of the 0-Hecke monoid, if my memory doesn't cheat me. You can look at the category that they form when combined with the cofaces. This might be a smaller category than the one you're looking for, but well worth some study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naive idea has to be slightly modified. The point is not to sort out all terms (it is a wrong intuition), but only where the variables $x_i$ are "alone". For example, the map $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto (x_2,x_1,\max(x_3,x_4),\min(x_3,x_4))$$ is not kept in the subcategory because $x_2$ which is alone is before $x_1$ which is alone. On the contrary, the map $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto (x_1,x_2,\max(x_3,x_4),\min(x_3,x_4))$$ will be kept.
This way, symmetry maps cannot show up by precomposing by coface maps, and the counterexample of the question cannot exist. Everything boils down to the following proposition ($\square$ is the box category, which is generated by the coface maps):

> **Proposition:** The set of maps $$\mathcal{A}=\{\phi:[1]^m\to[1]^n\in \widehat{\square}\mid \forall \delta:[1]^p\to [1]^m\in \square,
> \phi\delta \hbox{ one-to-one }\Rightarrow \phi\delta\in \square\}$$ is
> closed under composition and contains all identity maps. Moreover, the
> only one-to-one maps of $\mathcal{A}$ are the maps of $\square$.

**Proof:** Let $\phi_1,\phi_2\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\phi_1\phi_2$ exists. Let $\delta\in \square$ such that $\phi_1\phi_2\delta$ exists and is one-to-one. Then $\phi_2\delta$ is a one-to-one set map. Thus $\phi_2\delta\in \square$, $\phi_2$ belonging to $\mathcal{A}$. We deduce that $(\phi_1\phi_2)\delta =\phi_1(\phi_2\delta) \in \square$ since $\phi_1\in \mathcal{A}$. This means that $\phi_1\phi_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ by definition of $\mathcal{A}$. $\mathcal{A}$ contains clearly the identity maps. Finally suppose that $f:[1]^m\to [1]^n\in \mathcal{A}$ is one-to-one. Then $f\mathrm{id}_{[1]^m}$ is one-to-one, which implies that $f\in \square$.